# Is it possible to limit the maximum number of containers per docker image?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, host

**Problem:**
I have a couple of Docker images on a hosting server. I start multiple containers from a bunch of jenkins job. Due to limited capabilities of the host, I'd like to limit the maximum number of container per image. Setting the limit for the number of jenkins executors doesn't really solve the problem since some jobs can spin up 16 containers. It is possible though to split them into several threads of parallel executions, but this is still not ideal. I'd like to have one solution for all jobs

**Question #1 (main):**
Is it possible to set the maximum limit of containers Docker runs on a single machine to 10, and queue the rest of them?

**Question #2:**
If there is no such functionality or there are better options in this case, what is the workaroud for this?

Comment: Docker can’t do this on its own.  How would you address this problem if Docker wasn’t involved?

Comment: Why don't you use Kubernetes, or some other orchestrator?

Comment: @AAber never worked with kubernetes, but if it'll work, I'll definitely take a look

Comment: @DavidMaze I would set the limitation for the number of executors. Though that's not exactly solving all cases

Comment: An easy way to test Kubernetes on Ubuntu is Microk8s see: https://microk8s.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use kubetnetes as mentioned above. But this is very time consuming route

A simpler way is to set a master job that spins up your containers. Your pipeline will be calling this job, eg 16 times spinning up 16 containers. Then set a maximum of executors on your jenkins host for example to 6. When you kick off your job it will be 1 executor plus 16 in queue, total 17. It will start first 6, and then wait until then will be stopped. Once any of running containers is done, it will allow the next container to run

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to clean unused containers and images once in a while with a job.

Here it is:

https://gist.github.com/fredericrous/26e51ed936d710364fe1d1ab6572766e

Comment: I do that, but it's not enough. Every container is very heavy and the machine where I run them can't handle more than 10 of them, even when there is no other containers

Comment: Another workaround would be not to use docker but I guess you won't like this answer. Best workaround is to put some money in new hardware. The best thing would be to invest in a managed kubernetes cluster